# A specific way to pull out message list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a project where I am making a virtual phone and currently I need to have a list of people i've messaged. Basically the list you see before going into a private chat with X person.

My problem is currently I can't seem to find the solution to only get latest message I have with X person.

The issue with this is that if I've sent a message to X person and the X person have sent a message to me, i basically get 2 messages in the database when trying to pull out the information, where I only need to get the latest.

This is what I get when doing following and I ALMOST get what I want.
In JQUERY if I remove all where sender = my phone number i would run into a different issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxwLI.png

I've tried following sql

```sql
SELECT msg_id, sender, receiver, sender_msg, receiver_read, MAX(msg_date) 
FROM nl_phone_messages WHERE sender = '545-3169' OR receiver = '545-3169' GROUP BY sender, receiver
```

In this case you have to look at the numbers 114-5437 and 545-3169

msg_id 5 should not be in this list as it's not the latest message with this person where msg_id 24 is the latest with that specific person

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF1x3.png

I hope you understand my issue, ask if got any question - Thank you!

Comment: 1. I assume you try to get *latest* by `MAX(msg_date)`. Change it to `ORDER BY msg_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`. 2. In what format you store `msg_date`?

Comment: It's being saved as INT with length as 11 and i put it in as a timestamp - if that's your question

I am trying to get the latest message that I have with X person, but my query will divide the message if sender and receiver numbers are not the same

Comment: Seems to be unrelated to jQuery - I edited your tags.